# static column name in pivot table

Tags: pivot, unpivot

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


select @cols = '[1015],[1060],[1261],[1373]'

print @cols



set @query = 'SELECT header, ' + @cols + ' 
              from 
             (
                select product_id, header, value
                from
                (
                  select 
                        cast(product_id  as varchar(100))product_id , 
                        cast(product_name  as varchar(100)) product_name,
                        cast(product_price as varchar(100)) product_price, 
                        cast(product_weight as  varchar(100))product_weight,
                        cast((select TOP 1  image_name from tblProductImage where tblProductImage.product_id=tblProduct.product_id) as  varchar(100)) ProductImage      
                  from tblProduct 

                ) p
                unpivot
                (
                  value
                  for header in (product_name, product_price, product_weight,ProductImage)
                ) unp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for product_id in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

I am using above query and its generating following output

[image]

Now my problem is i want that  column name should be static .. as there currently there max to max 5 columns out of them first column will be header which is OK

but for rest of column's i want also there names should be like Prodcut1,Product2,Product3, and Product4 . In case if there only three products then its also shows five columns but for last column all attributes value should be null

Comment: So you want the product columns names to be Product1, Product2, Product3 and Product4?  Since the product_id will not be the column headers, do you want another row with that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly then while you are passing in specific product_ids, you want the column names to be `Product1`, `Product2`, etc.

If that is correct, then you can create the static column names by applying `row_number()`.

Your code will be adjusted to the following:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @prods AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @prods = '141,142,143,144'

set @query = 'SELECT header, Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4
              from 
              (
                select header, value,
                  ''Product''+cast(row_number() over(partition by header 
                                                   order by header) as varchar(10)) prods
                from
                (
                  select 
                    cast(product_id as varchar(10)) product_id,
                    product_name, 
                    cast(product_price as varchar(10)) product_price, 
                    product_weight
                  from tblProduct
                  where product_id in ('+@prods+') 
                ) p
                unpivot
                (
                  value
                  for header in (product_name, product_price, product_weight, product_id)
                ) unp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for prods in (Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4)
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/defb7/14). This gives the result:

```
|         HEADER | PRODUCT1 | PRODUCT2 | PRODUCT3 | PRODUCT4 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     product_id |      141 |      142 |      143 |      144 |
|   product_name |     A141 |     A144 |     A143 |     A142 |
|  product_price |      300 |     4000 |     5000 |      200 |
| product_weight |    200gm |    100gm |    400gm |    300gm |
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the order of Header column .. I want Product Name, Product Image, Price, Weight

Comment: @rahularyansharma What version of sql server?

Comment: sql server 2008 r2 ...  but i have done using case statement in final sql for column name . something like this    'select header, value,    
   'Product'+cast(row_number() over(partition by header     
   order by header) as varchar(10)) prods, CASE header WHEN 'Product Name' THEN 1 
                WHEN 'Product Image' THEN 2
                WHEN 'Price' THEN 3
                WHEN 'Weight' THEN 4
                ELSE   5 END as 'num' '

Comment: @rahularyansharma Since you are using SQL Server 2008 you can use CROSS APPLY to unpivot and you can define a sort order column -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/defb7/15 -- or you can use a `CASE`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27169/discussion-between-rahularyansharma-and-bluefeet)